# Scorecard was not counting the correct number with A CASE and THEN 1 ELSE 0 statement at some conditions

Tags: looker-studio

[No comparison metric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QGjT2.png)

When I use the A CASE and "THEN 1 ELSE 0" statement to count text, but the scorecard was showing the wrong number when I insert date range at these conditions:

1. With a metric comparison
2. Inserted date range control (this quarter)
3. (in table form), when sorted by the custom field

e.g.[with comparison and this quarter date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5zma.png)

BUT sometimes, it work for just a while:
[with comparison but this year date range](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVI0n.png)

This is my raw data in Google Sheet:
[raw data column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1Q9U.png)

I created custom fields for "TRUE", "FALSE" and "UNDEFINED" as formula below:
[Custom fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XP21K.png)

The formula should be correct but it seemed with the bugs. Please help